# casting reflected value to type in golang?

Tags: go, reflection

Is it possible to dynamically cast a value generated by reflect.Zero/New back to an arbitrary type?

https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection seems to suggest not (as go is statically typed). That pretty much seems to limit the uses of reflection as far as I can see, as you always need to be aware of the type you are working with.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type A struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {

    a := &A{Name: "Dave"}
    fmt.Println(a)

    //create a nil pointer of an arbitrary type
    dynamicType := reflect.TypeOf(a)
    dynamicNil := reflect.Zero(dynamicType).Interface()
    a = dynamicNil //is it possible to do this without explicitly casting to A (ie. avoiding `a = dynamicNil.(*A)`)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Comment: Type casting doesn't exist at all in Go. Although that doesn't affect the core of your question.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking - there's no way to do a type assertion without a type assertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question's prose and code contradict.

In your code, `dynamicNil` has the type `interface{}`, not `reflect.Value` as the prose suggests. As `a` has concrete type `*A` you'll have to type-assert `dynamicNil` to `*A`. There's no way around that.

Also note that Go doesn't have casts -- only type-conversions and assertions.

Edit: maybe you're looking for `reflect.Value.Set`? it's unclear to me.

Comment: thanks for the answer - i've tried to clarify the question.

Comment: i ended up with a much simpler solution that didnt involve reflection (which is really the 'go' way of doing it)

came back to this question out of curiosity, and think this solves the issue i was trying to work around (thanks for the hint on reflect.Value.Set):

`reflect.ValueOf(&a).Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(dynamicNil))`